# Is there a rectifier scheme for tri-phase which is more efficient than the bridge rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, power-electronics, efficiency, three-phase, bridge

[image]

Because of the topology of tri-phase bridge rectifier, every phase is active (i.e.; feeding the load) only for 33% of the time. It feels like we are not fully utilizing all the three phases, and because of that the output impedance of the rectifier is higher than it could actually be.

Is there an alternative rectifier form which utilizes all three phases (or all N-phases in general). For example, by pumping charge in a storage element in a sub-interval of one period, and using it in another sub-interval.

Assmue that the load is always resistive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The energy efficiency of a three phase rectifier is pretty high in my book but if you're only wanting to push energy into a resistive load then make yourself a star-connected load of resistors. This will be perfect - no losses in diodes at all.

If, on the other hand you are requiring a DC output then consider what high power switch mode power supplies do - nowadays they have to correct for surges and non-ideal power factors by trying to utilize energy from the input waveform all the way along and as such they "strive" to present a near resistive load to the incoming AC.

Comment: This is called "[Power Factor Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Active_PFC)" (PFC) and there are three-phase as well as single-phase designs.